# Cloning repository from local git server to AWS Ubuntu

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I have a git server which is a CentOS server machine where repositories are already available.
There is one AWS Ubuntu server where would like to clone repository from above CentOS git server.
Now while use git clone command, getting below error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Git Command: 'git clone ssh://@:22/repository1'

Please help to resolve the issue?

**Note:**
If the similar question is already available, please share the link.

Comment: This is not a git issue, it is an SSH issue, which git is using.  See http://edoceo.com/notabene/ssh-exchange-identification

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to SSH to other servers successfully? If you can't then I would suspect a network configuration issue - egress traffic blocked either by security group, IP tables, or a proxy.

If you can SSH elsewhere then I suspect there is a firewall on the Git server that is blocking your IP address. Any further info that you can provide will also help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your quick comment.
Actually the issue is resolved by adding sshd <Clinet IP> in /etc/hosts.allow of Git server.

Comment: Exactly as the second part of the answer referred to.  Sorry I didn't provide the exact details to check. Glad to hear it is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Let me share the solution which is applied this time.

Added `sshd <Clinet IP>` in /etc/hosts.allow file of Git server.

And Cloning is okay now.